# what is "who do you think that is?"

Tags: grammar

In *Harry Potter*, Ron, pointing at professor Lupin, said this to Hermione:

> *Who do you think that is?*

And she answered:

> *Profesor R.J.Rupin.*

I searched for the expression:
**'Who that is?'**
And one dictionary said, it means:
**'Who does it belong to?'**

Is this correct? Isn't the second thing talking about things? (I mean it is about the things like non-person?)
And if this sentence is right, isn't it a rude expression for senior citizens?

If there is something wrong with my question, tell me! thank you!

Comment: _Who that is_ does not mean _Who does it belong to?_. That would be _Whose is that?_ No, it isn't rude - _that_ means _that person_, so it isn't treating them as though they were a thing.

Comment: "And if this sentence is right, isn't it a rude expression for senior citizens?" — as an aside, the phrase ['senior citizen'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_age#Senior_citizen) is generally used only for pensioners (~65+), rather than anyone older than you. The books putting Lupin at 30s-40s, he definitely wouldn't qualify as one :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pronoun 'that' can be used to indicate a person, thing, idea, state, event, time, remark, etc.

Asking "who do you think that is?" or simply "who is that?" is a way of asking someone to identify another person that is present, has been mentioned, or has been indicated by you in some way.

The use of "who **do you think** that is?" makes it more about the other person's opinion or knowledge. You could ask this question sincerely, not knowing the identity of the party in question, or you could ask knowing who it is, but inviting someone to give their thoughts.